# class derived from list

Tags: c#

I have a C# class derived from a generic list

```
public class CostCodes : List<CostCode>
{

    public CostCodes() : base()
    {
        Add(new CostCode { Description = "DOM0010 Fall Arr", ID = 1599 });
        Add(new CostCode { Description = "DOM0020 Acoustics", ID = 1600 });
    }
```

when I try to use the Find method on this derived class, no find method appears in intellisense.

```
var codes = new CostCodes();

CostCode costCode = codes.Find(...
```

Figured out that the problem was being caused by the classes being in the test silverlight project. Moved them out, but it would be good to know why it made a difference.

-- UPDATE --

Cant answer my own question yet, but for those who are interested, this article shows why

http://forums.silverlight.net/t/67428.aspx/1

Apparently there is no Find method in silverlight projects. You have to use linq and the "first" method instead of find

```
using System.Linq;

var costCode = codes.First(cc => cc.ID == id);
```

Comment: What kind of object is codes?

Comment: Sorry, missed out the code that initialises CostCodes codes = new CostCodes()

Comment: Restart Visual Studio :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this a problem with IntelliSense?

This compiles fine:

```
public class CostCode {
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class CostCodes : List<CostCode> {
    public CostCodes()
        : base() {
        Add(new CostCode {Description = "DOM0010 Fall Arr"});
        Add(new CostCode {Description = "DOM0020 Acoustics"});
    }
}

// In another class...
public static void Main(string[] argStrings) {
    CostCodes s = new CostCodes();
    var hasDescription = s.Find(cc => cc.Description != null);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. I was testing the code in a silverlight project for a prototype so this may be the problem. Works outside of the silverlight project. Thanks for the lambda expression. was just about to write it :)

Answer (score 0):

The `Find()` method should appear in intellisense.

I can only hypothesize that perhaps your line `var codes = new CostCodes();` is referencing a type named `CostCodes` in a different namespace.

Try this:

```
var codes = new Full.Namespace.CostCodes();
```